# this.state on setState callback function after this.setState()

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to access this.state inside this.setState after a state is updated.
I want user info to be set to state then from that source of truth wanted to save that user data into local storage

```
setUserInfo = userInfo => {
  this.setState(
    { username: userInfo.userName, password: userInfo.userPass },
    prevState => {
      //trying to access this.state but unable to
      console.log(prevState);
      // or
      console.log(this.state.username);
    }
  );
};
```

I know that this could code could do it but will the second setstate be confirm to run after the first setState?

```
setUserInfo = userInfo => {
  this.setState({ username: userInfo.userName, password: userInfo.userPass });
  this.setState(prevState => {
    prevState;
  });
};
```

Comment: you can use userInfo.userName inside call function instead of this.state.username

Comment: doesnt that defeat the purpose of single source of truth?

Comment: What does 'unable to' mean? Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can replicate the problem. It's expected that `prevState` is updated state inside a callback. *will the second setstate be confirm to run after the first setState?* - it will, but you don't need second setState.

Answer (score 1):

did you bind the function

inside your constructor() bind the function

`this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)`

```
handleClick() {
    this.setState({ status: 2 }, () => {
      console.log(this.state);
    });
  }
```

Actually this should work

Comment: No, it shouldn't work, `setUserInfo` is clearly an arrow and already bound to class context.

Comment: This code is incoherent with the code posted in the question. `setUserInfo` is already an arrow.

Comment: what do you mean. ?
`console.log(this.state.username);`
this should work in setState callback, what it returns?

Comment: I mean that `setUserInfo` is already arrow function, and binding it with `bind` doesn't provide any improvement over original code.

Comment: yeah you are right no need to bind , its my mistake. but `console.log(this.state.username);` should work there what it returns?

Comment: Yes, it should if everything was done correctly. It's unclear why it didn't work in the first place. I asked the OP to elaborate further.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192028/discussion-between-habeeb-rahman-and-estus).

Answer (score 0):

`this` inside the `setState()` function refers to methods of `setState` so differentiate these two `this`'s. Set `var that = this` so you can use it like `that.state.username`

```js
var that = this;

this.setState(
  { username: userInfo.userName, password: userInfo.userPass },
  prevState => {
    //tring to access this.state.username but unable to
    console.log(prevState.username, that.state.username);
  }
);
```